# How to hook api in windows phone 7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there something allow me to develop a software in wp7 just like API MONITOR in windows?

Comment: Before we can begin to help we need more information. Generally though you could not 'hook' a native API via WP7's Compact Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Phone has some native API hooks (although undocumeted):
http://blog.walshie.me/2010/11/12/windows-phone-7-native-apps-the-missing-link

However, due to the restrictive nature of the OS you might have problems in tracking down API calls from other applications, since you will need to have your own app running in the background, and that is currently the privilege given to system apps only.